# How can you show that people are showing antipathy towards a character without using or by using minimal dialogues in a comics?

Tags: creative-writing, dialogue, comics

How can you show that people are showing antipathy towards a character without using or by using minimal dialogues in a comics? I was thinking of putting some panels where some characters are seen walking away from the character saying "You should stay away from him he's dangerous.", "Fucking creep!", "He gives me the creep.", "He's insane!" etc. but it sounds a bit too forced and since these characters aren't important at all anyways, I am thinking there's a better way. Also, what about semi-important and other important characters? How should we handle them? What are some common ways to achieve this, I am thinking the less amount of dialogues the better.

Comment: Exactly how you do this depends on the genre, whether you are being naturalistic or happy having something more expressionistic or kids-comics style. You could draw other people looking repulsed (which could be naturalistic or not), or draw the character in a creepy fashion (as others see them, if you're happy with an impressionistic approach)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you change your dialogue examples to be things people are thinking rather than saying out loud, it would be more natural.
2. Show body posture
3. Show behavior (people actually walking away, or pulling back, or denying service, or giving looks that are definitely negative, etc.)